# Jquery Radio box checked find is showing previously checked Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html

```
<div   class="calsort btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary ">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="rcal1" autocomplete="off" checked="checked">rcal1</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="rcal2" autocomplete="off">rcal2</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options"  id="rcal3" autocomplete="off">rcal3</label>
</div>
```

And my javascript

```
$( ".calsort" ).click(function() {

$(".calsort :checked").each(function() {
rcal = this.id;
    alert(rcal);
});
});
```

So when I test this function in js fiddle it works...But when i test in work environment with other js codes this is not working...But This function is alone does not involve with any other variable name or function name.

My problem is When i click rcal2 button it alerts rcal1 first and when i click 2nd time it alerts rcal2.And same for rcal3 button..First time it alerts previously checked value.

Can some one tell alternative way to check which box is checked...I dont want $(this) method..because Other functions too will be using this loop way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening when you click on the `lable` instead of the `radio button`. The reason is the previously checked button is not cleared at the time when the click event happens when you click on the label. It happens even in a jsfiddle (try clicking on the lable [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a1uyjop0/)).

Try this instead,

```js
$( ".calsort input" ).click(function() {
    var rcal = this.id;
    alert(rcal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div   class="calsort btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary ">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="rcal1" autocomplete="off" checked="checked">rcal1</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="rcal2" autocomplete="off">rcal2</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options"  id="rcal3" autocomplete="off">rcal3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: hey how can I use this in loop ?

Comment: $(".calsort :checked").each(function() {

Comment: For the radio buttons, You can only select one radio button for once. Why do you want a loop here?

Comment: Like I have another 2 functions , I wanna check which button is checked from there too..I have mentioned in question too

Comment: Where do you call that 2 functions?

Comment: Use `$(".calsort :checked").attr('id')`

Comment: when I use that only I get delay

Comment: If you create a `jsfiddle` I could help. I'm not getting exactly what you need with your description.

Comment: never mind i used global variable and accecced it in all fucntion

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do, instead of `.click()` event have used `.change()` . 
Radio button on `.change()` event is good way to get selected value.

**JS:**

[working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/satinder_singh1/e3ggoqb7/1/)

```
$(".calsort input").on('change', function () {
    var self = jQuery(this);
    var aResult = self.is(":checked");
    if (aResult) {
        alert(self.attr('id'));
    }
});
```